# What mounting solution should be used to mount this wine rack?

Tags: drywall, walls, mounting, hanging, drywall-anchor

My mother wants to hang this wine rack on the wall, but the product was not originally designed to be mounted.

How can she securely mount the wine rack so that it sits as illustrated in the photo? It's an awkward and relatively small portion of drywall, so she didn't detect any studs that she could drill into.

The dimensions on the solid wood wine rack are: 19"W x 6"D x 8.75”H.

The rack weighs 6 pounds on its own. The standard weight of a wine bottle is a little over 2.5 lbs. Ideally, the mounting solution will allow for the storage of 4 bottles at a time, thus it will need to be able to support 16 to 20 lbs. total.

We greatly appreciate any advice. If you don't think it's feasible, your input is also welcome.

P.S. My crappy drawing is not to scale.

[image: Mockup of hanging orientation]
[image: Clear picture of the wine rack's construction]
[image: Picture of the intended use case]

Answer (score 3):

You want to find studs. Do not use drywall anchors or else you will find a thousand dollar bottle of wine staining the carpet.

I would use a nice backing board(stained wood) and mount it as a shelf, with shelf brackets.

Screw a piece of wood to cover studs to mount the wine rack on.

Comment: It's probably not worth the effort, but I do appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 0):

I would drill holes in the 4 corners and use screws into strong drywall anchors. For the best look, you could countersink the screw heads and cover them with wood plugs that match the color of the wine rack.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously no back and very little surfaces to mount any type of hook or loop to be attached by screws.

We also do not know how the rack itself is held together. It may not be designed to carry the weight of wine bottles and hanging could cause a messy situation if the unit comes apart.

My advice is do not hang it.  It was not designed to be hung.

Answer (score 0):

that is a 14 inch wall. Your studs will be on the end. Cannot drill into them to put your wine rack in place.

The wine rack looks like someone could hang off of it. Asssuming that a small child will put all of their weight on it. possible jumping up and then grabbing it, so your anchoring system will need to support the weight of a falling small child.

That being said:

There are 2 options.

1. (What I would do) Open up that wall, install 2x4s where you want to screw the wine rack into the wall. Close the wall up, mud, paint. Install the wine rack.
2. (The easier way).

Use either Simpson Strong-Tie FlipToggle anchors (Which can support 188 pounds a piece) or Snaptoggle drywall anchors (which support up to 265 pounds).

Comment: Why *can't* the OP drill into the studs?

Comment: He doesn't want to put it in the middle of the wall, where there are no studs.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  (I assume you mean "he *wants* to put it in the middle.")

Comment: @Huesmann at least that is what I interpret his drawing to mean... If I am wrong he could just screw into the stud.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a stud on the corner. If you come 1-1/4” left of the corner, you’ll be in the middle of it.

Flush the rack with the corner and get 2 or 3 good 3” screws into the stud. On the other side, use toggles. (Snap toggles are really nice; butterfly toggles would work.)